# Returning object keeps incrementing retainCount

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, retain

I have a class which inherits from an interface

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <IMyClass> {
   NativeCppObject* _myInternalObj;
}

-(id) initWithInternalObj:(NativeCppObject*) myInternalObj;

@end
```

Then I have a factory class that creates this object

```
-(id<IMyClass>) createMyClass:(NSString*)myInternalObjParameter
{

  NativeCppObject* nativeObj = new NativeCppObject(...);  
  MyClass ret = [[MyClass alloc] initWithInternalObj:nativeObj];
  return ret;
}
```

Now the problem that I have is when I chain those calls from createMyClass return value, the returned `ret` keeps getting referenced and never released. At the end of my chain, I get like 5 retain counts which prevents my object from dealloc correctly.

those calls are like

```
@implementation MyClassFactory
+(id<IMyClass>) createMyClass:(NSString*) param
{
  return [gFactory createMyClass:param];
}
@end
```

gFactory is a static id. I know this is not the best practice but at the moment it cannot be trivially changed.

When calling createMyClass from MyClassFactory, the retain count is like 3. Wrapping this into other "factories" just makes more calls to retain and no new call to release. I don't get why this happens.

EDIT:

This is weird. While stepping in the code, I hit "return ret" twice. retain seems to be called twice as well.

EDIT2:

I have a class that needs this factory. In fact this is a test case so some code aims to be generic

```
-(id<IMyClass>) setupMyObjectAndStuff
{
  NSString* param;
  return [self setupMyObjectAndStuff:param];
}


-(id<IMyClass>) setupMyObjectAndStuff:(NSString*) param
{
  return [MyClassFactory createMyClass:param];
}
```

Then in my main function, after calling

```
id<IMyClass> myClass = [self setupMyObjectAndStuff];
```

MyClass retain will have been called like 3 or 4 times and release will only have been called once or twice.

Comment: Never use retain count. Ever. Don't do it. There may be a problem but relying on retain count will only ever make your problem worse. Retain count is never reliable. Don't use it. I'm not sure if I mentioned this yet but don't use retain count. Ever.

Comment: Ok, but dealloc is never called. Ever =)

Comment: If I override retain/release and make my own retain count, the result is identical

Comment: Here you go. http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Ok. It's all very complicated. Is it essential for you to have this generic class factory thingy? Also, ignoring retain release etc... Are you having any specific problems with this? Ie are you seeing increased memory usage etc...

Comment: Well MyClass is not dealloc, which leads to other problems later on. MyClass needs to be deallocated before the threading system shuts down for example.

Comment: Can you show more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my objects were not wrapped in @autoreleasepool{ ... }

Changing the calling code to :

```
@autoreleasepool{
  id<IMyClass> myClass = [self setupMyObjectAndStuff];
  // ... snip ...
  myClass = nil;
}
```

cause the objects to be deallocated as soon as there were no more references to them. Instruments was correctly showing the number of retainCount and all but one of those were autorelease retains.